# How do you stream results from Node/Express REST endpoint but with a delay on each document returned?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, server-sent-events

A bit of a background, I come from a Java background and I already got this problem working. However, I'm trying to transition to Node/Express/Mongoose for the same problem.

To summarize, I have a REST endpoint to fetch a list of events (meetings, parties, etc.) sorted by date. However, I'd like to stream these results from the Mongo database one JSON document at a time with a delay of 100ms.

Right now, my code returns all the events as one result instead of chopping them up into individual documents and streaming them one at a time.

We're using Angular with EventSource() as the client. I know my Angular code works because everything works fine with my Java backend code.

Here's what I presently have:

```
app.get('/events', (req, res) => {

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    });

    Event.find({}).sort({ date:1 }).then(events => {

            console.log(events);

            res.write(JSON.stringify(events) + '\n');

        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message
            });
        });

});
```

I also tried this:

```
var stream = Event.find({}).sort({ date: 1 }).stream();

    stream.on('data', function(doc) {
        //console.log(doc);
        res.write(JSON.stringify(doc));
    });

    stream.on('end', function() {
        res.end();
    });
```

And this:

```
var cursor = Event.find().sort({ date: 1}).cursor();

    cursor.on('data', function(doc) {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(doc));
    });

    cursor.on('close', function() {
        res.end();
    });
```

I'm hoping the answer would be simple, but due to my newbie nature in Node, I'm not even sure what I'm looking for. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: You are not adding any delay to the back. You are sending them all at once. Look for "cursors" in mongoose.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Hey Jorge, yes, I figured that, but I'm not sure how to do delays in Node and where exactly it goes. In my 3rd code sample above, I used cursors, but I don't know where the delay code goes or even how it looks like. Any ideas or links? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not used to mongoose, but what you have to do is to get one item (cursor->next or something like that) send it, wait some time with `setTimeout()` and then send the next item with the cursor->next thingy again. A cursor is something like "receive items on-the-fly", and usually you can ask for the next item when you want.